# how do i define first html's variable to the second html by element

Tags: javascript, html

at index.html

```js
function pay(id)
{
    localStorage.thing = id;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="opt1" onclick="pay(this.id)" onclick="window.location.href = 'payment.html'"></button>
```

at payment.html

```js
window.onload = function() 
{
    def();
};

function def()
{
    document.getElementById('card').innerHTML = localStorage.thing;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="card"></h1>
```

my main goal is to define button's id from payment.html page through element but when i click the button nothing's working.

Comment: You have two `onclick`-handlers on the button. If you really need both, then make it into a function.

Comment: @Zeth +1. I'm leaving an upvote because I wouldn't have come up with the idea of defining multiple onclick attributes. I had to check if it actually works. Spoiler: it doesn't.

Comment: @Zeth
The 2 onclicks are both restrictions? By that means I need to know how can I transfer to a new page using a function.

Comment: @if_statement In HTML you can only have an attribute specified once, not multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change the first part to this:

```
function pay(id)
{
    localStorage.thing = id;
    window.location.href = 'payment.html'
}
```

And the markdown to this:

```
<button type="button" id="opt1" onclick="pay(this.id)">
  Button text
</button>
```